# MD5 Hashing a CSV with Python

Tags: python, csv, hash

I have a csv with email addresses that needs to be hashed in MD5 format, then save the hashed emails as a new csv. I haven't seen my exact use case on SO and haven't been able to successfully modify existing questions.

Original file path is `"/Users/[username]/Downloads/email_original.csv"` and desired output file would be `"/Users/[username]/Downloads/email_hashed.csv"`.

Original File

```
email_addr
fake_email1@yahoo.com
fake_email2@gmail.com
fake_email3@college.edu
fake_email4@hotmail.com
fake_email5@ford.com
```

Hashed File

```
email_addr
0x3731BF23851200A7607BA554EEAF7912
0xA5D5D3B99896D32BAC64162BD56BE177
0xAE03858BDFBDF622AF5A1852317500C3
0xC870F8D75180AC9DA2188129C910489B
0xD7AFD8085548808459BDEF8665C8D52A
```

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? It will help to show your current best attempt and explain the specific problem.

Comment: Extract the data, then hash it with `hashlib.md5` if it's _not_ equal to `email_addr` and then write to a file.

Comment: This isn't a software-writing service. I charge people money to write apps for them. But we will gladly *help* you where you're stuck, *after* showing what you've attempted.

Comment: That's the thing, I can't write it from scratch and the examples seem to be way more complex than what I need. On SO I've tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035533/python-hash-not-being-updated-in-csv-file-output but it's way more complicated than what I'm trying to do. It does seem the `hashlib library` is what I need but I'm open to whatever.

Comment: Take a look at this. You can modify it to skip the first line. https://linuxreference.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/howto-compute-md5-hash-each-sentence-in-file-using-python/

Comment: @obscurite That get's me VERY close. If I do this I get it to print, just not sure how to write it to a new csv instead of printing: `import hashlib
import string

file=open("/Users/[username]/Downloads/email_original.csv",'rb')

for line in file.xreadlines():
     line=line.strip()
     print hashlib.md5(line).hexdigest()

file.close `

Comment: It's great that you're close. Now you just need to google how to write to a file in python. Piece of cake. :)

Comment: @obscurite Piece of cake if you know what you're doing, but thank you. I'm now much closer to my goal.

Comment: An example has been added that should meet the requirements of your request and also provides some features for improved flexibility in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer in your comment is nearly correct. You only need to `open` another file with the write attribute `w`. I have changed your query to use `with` so you don't to have to explicitly close the file handlers:

```
with open("/Users/[username]/Downloads/email_original.csv",'rb')  as file:
    with open("/Users/[username]/Downloads/email_hashed.csv",'w')  as output:
        for line in file: 
           line=line.strip() 
           print hashlib.md5(line).hexdigest() 
           output.write(hashlib.md5(line).hexdigest() +'\n')
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much @Jaco

Comment: Hey @Jaco when I run this on my actual file w/millions of emails it only prints 7 hashed emails in the terminal and only saves those 7 in the "..._hashed.csv" file. Thoughts on why it only does a few? There are no errors.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my test file. Does each line have a carriage return?

Comment: It's odd, but it is something on my side re: file. I will investigate but the code is fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Jaco**'s answer is good but incomplete since it neglects the encoding for the MD5 hash. The code would also be insufficient if the CSV format was modified to include other columns in the future. Here is an example that tackles both problems while also making easy to change the hash in the future along with specifying other columns that can have individual hash algorithms applied to them:

```
import csv
import hashlib

IN_PATH = 'email_original.csv'
OUT_PATH = 'email_hashed.csv'
ENCODING = 'ascii'
HASH_COLUMNS = dict(email_addr='md5')


def main():
    with open(IN_PATH, 'rt', encoding=ENCODING, newline='') as in_file, \
            open(OUT_PATH, 'wt', encoding=ENCODING, newline='') as out_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(in_file)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, reader.fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in reader:
            for column, method in HASH_COLUMNS.items():
                data = row[column].encode(ENCODING)
                digest = hashlib.new(method, data).hexdigest()
                row[column] = '0x' + digest.upper()
            writer.writerow(row)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I get this error when I run your version: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in main
TypeError: file() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)`

Comment: @FrankB. You might be getting this error in the Python 2.x series of interpreters. The code should be fine if you run it in the latest version of Python 3 instead.